# How to change third bit in binary representation?

Tags: c#

I'm trying to write code in which code the third bit is always one.

I've done the following to detect the third bit, but i don't know how to change it to show one , it should be done without using loops,  because this exercise is from first part of book for beginners and in this chapter there is information about variables and operators in c#.

```
int decimalNumber = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
string binaryConv = Convert.ToString(decimalNumber, 2);
char thirdBite = binaryConv[2];
```

Comment: Reverse the process. Set the value to `'1'`, convert to an `Int32` with the appropriate base, then do what you want with the number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What if you just **[OR](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/csharp/csharp_bitwise_operators.htm)** the number with 4 (100 in binary)? This will ensure that 3rd bit is always set:

```
using System;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Console.Write("Enter integer value: ");
        int intVal = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.WriteLine("You entered: {0} (In binary this number is: {1})", intVal, Convert.ToString(intVal, 2));
        Console.WriteLine("{0} | 4 (100 in binary) = {1} (In binary this number is: {2})", intVal, intVal | 4, Convert.ToString(intVal | 4, 2));
    }
}
```

**Example Usage 1:**

```
Enter integer value: 2
You entered: 2 (In binary this number is: 10)
2 | 4 (100 in binary) = 6 (In binary this number is: 110)
```

**Example Usage 2:**

```
Enter integer value: 49
You entered: 49 (In binary this number is: 110001)
49 | 4 (100 in binary) = 53 (In binary this number is: 110101)
```

**Example Usage 3:**

```
Enter integer value: -6
You entered: -6 (In binary this number is: 11111111111111111111111111111010)
-6 | 4 (100 in binary) = -2 (In binary this number is: 11111111111111111111111111111110)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
int decimalNumber = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine()) | 4;
```

The 4 is the 3rd binary digit (100 base 2 = 4 base 10).

The | is a binary OR

Answer (score 1):

Welcome.  Your solution *will* give you the third bit.  But it does it by converting to a string, which is way more expensive then it needs to be.

Get the value of the third bit like this:

```
 bool thirdBit = (decimalNumber & (1 << 2)) != 0;
```

Make sure the 3rd bit is set ON:

```
 decimalNumber = decimalNumber | (1 << 2);
```

Make sure the 3rd bit is set OFF:

```
 decimalNumber = decimalNumber & ~(1 << 2);
```